# Why does my security group rule not work when calling from the private to public subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I have a server in a private subnet in SG1, and I want to make a call to a load balancer in a public subnet in SG2.

I have my outbound rule set up on SG1 which allows traffic to SG2.

However, when I add a rule to allow Inbound traffic from SG2 that allows SG1 inbound, the request times out.  If I add an open rule to SG2 the request work!  I've also tried with the private IP address range, but that did not work.

How do I add a correct rule to the load balancer so that traffic is allowed from SG1, and I do not expose the security group to be publicly open?

Comment: How do you call the LB from private subnet? Using its public dns name? It will not work if your private has no internet access.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue is caused by the fact that you are connecting to an **Internet-facing load balancer**.

The load balancer is being referenced via a DNS Name. This name is resolving to a **public IP address** because the load balancer is accessible to the Internet.

When the instance in the private subnet accesses the load balancer, it is actually resolving the ELB DNS Name to a public IP address, so **the request is actually leaving the VPC, then coming back in**. This means that the "from" IP address is coming from the private instance's *public* IP address, not its private IP address. The security group is only expecting the private instance's *private* IP address, so it is not recognizing the incoming traffic.

If the Load Balancer is only being used in this manner, then it should be created as an **internal Load Balancer**, rather than being public. It is also possible to create *two* load balancers (one Internet-facing, one internal-only).

Comment: Good answer! I have a minor improvement to add. The security group on the load balancer won't even see the "from" ip of a private instance because there is no route to the internet/IGW, so the packet won't be route to the load balancer.

Comment: Agreed. If a NAT Gateway is in use, the traffic would appear to be coming from the public IP address of the NAT Gateway, not the instance itself.